# Typescript object property incorrect type

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to write a simple Discord bot in TypeScript, using [discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js) and [clime](https://github.com/vilic/clime).

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to access an object property of a context object that I pass around, but it's always null. When I check the properties using either vscode's debugger or console.log, the object seems to have all of the properties that I would expect, except they're all nested one layer too deep.

```
export class DiscordCommandContext extends Context {
    public message:Message;
    public client:Client;

    constructor (options:ContextOptions, message:Message, client:Client) {
        super(options);

        this.message = message;
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

When I try accessing it the message property, it's always falsy (if block is skipped over).

```
if (context.message.guild) {
    var settings = await repo.getRealmSettings(+context.message.guild.id);

    if (key) {
        embed.fields.push({name:key,value:settings[key]});
    } else {
        Object.keys(settings).forEach(property => {
        embed.fields.push({name:property,value:settings[property]});
        });
    }
}
```

But in the console, I see this:
[DiscordCommandContext appears to have nested "message" objects, one of the wrong type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxUZ.png)

I cannot access context.message.message, I get "Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Message'", which is as I would expect.

**EDIT 1**

My instantiation code looked like this:

```
var options:ContextOptions = {
    commands: argArr,
    cwd: ""
};

var context = new DiscordCommandContext(options, this.message, this.client );
```

Where argArr is a split string passed into the method and both this.message and this.client are populated in the constructor of the calling class (none are null)

I managed to get DiscordCommandContext to function properly by changing it to this:

```
export class DiscordCommandContext extends Context {
    public message:Message;
    public client:Client;
    public realmSettings: RealmSettings;

    constructor (options:ContextOptions, contextExtension:DiscordCommandContextValues) {
        super(options);

        this.message = contextExtension.message;
        this.client = contextExtension.client;
        this.realmSettings = contextExtension.realmSettings
    }
}

export interface DiscordCommandContextValues {
    message:Message;
    client:Client;
    realmSettings: RealmSettings;
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
var context = new DiscordCommandContext(options, {message:this.message, client:this.client, realmSettings: settings} );
```

I'm not sure if that's the right way or not... but it works.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are instantiating a `DiscordCommantContext`?

Comment: @jered I have updated the question with the requested info, as well as what I did to get it working for now.